# bind9 ubuntu set up correctly, quit working

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

*While I'm talking about Chef a bit here, I'm fairly confident the problem has nothing to do with Chef)*
We manage all of our Linux (Ubuntu) servers, which are running our web infrastructure, with Chef, and I was migrating everything over to be managed by a new Chef server. All our servers are running on an internal network loadbalanced with haproxy, and dns/dhcp is handled by 2 servers running bind9 and isc-dhcp-server. 
It was running fine before the move, it was running fine after the move, then when I was finishing things up, *dns just stopped working.* Which brought everything down. No changes to the servers should have been made.

I've tried:

- restarting the service
- checking all the conf files
- when I tried turning on logging, the service would fail to start
- I've looked at syslog, I don't see anything helpful...

I'm at a loss. I need to get my services back up.
At this point I've just been up for too many hours straight, and I know I'm probably just missing something simple.

Not sure what code/output would be helpful...

haaaaaallppp

Comment: How does turning on logging prevent the service from starting? That would indicate a config error. You *need* some error output to tell you what the problem is. Try starting named by hand (as root of course).

Comment: Thanks, I was just too tired and not thinking straight. Wasn't a bind problem, it was a problem with the dhcp service, figured it all out from syslog and got it solved.